# Please find how to enter employee details,update,remove,displaying using hashmap

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

class Employee
{
private String Id;
private String Name;
private String Department;
private String Salary;

public Employee(String Id, String Name, String Department,
String Salary)
{
this.Id=Id;
this.Name=Name;
this.Department=Department;
this.Salary=Salary;
}

public String getId() {
return Id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
Id = id;
}
public String getName() {
return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
Name = name;
}
public String getDepartment() {
return Department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
Department = department;
}
public String getSalary() {
return Salary;
}
public void setSalary(String salary) {
Salary = salary;
}

public String toString() 
{ 
return this.Id+"\t"+this.Name+"\t\t"+this.Department+"\t\t\t"+this.Salary;
}
}


public class Assignment4 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

try {

Map< String, List<Employee> > m=new HashMap< String, List<Employee> >();
List<Employee> ListForFinance=new ArrayList<Employee>();
Scanner scn1=new Scanner(System.in);
String Id;
String Name;
String Department;
String Salary;

while(true)
{
System.out.print("\nThe Choices:\n1>add\n2>modification\n3>remove\n4>display\n\n");
System.out.println("Enter the choice: ");
System.out.println("To quit type -1");
int num=scn1.nextInt();
if(num == -1)
{
break;
}

switch(num)
{
case 1:
{
System.out.print("\nDepartment: ");
Department=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\nId: ";
Id=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\nName: ");
Name=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\nSalary: ");
Salary=scn1.next();

Employee employee1=new Employee(Id,Name,Department,Salary);
ListForFinance.add(employee1);
m.put(Department, ListForFinance);
break;
}

case 2:
{
System.out.println("Type Department to be modified");
Department=scn1.next();
System.out.println("Modification values");
System.out.print("\nId: ");
Id=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\nName: ");
Name=scn1.next();
System.out.print("\nSalary: ";
Salary=scn1.next();

Set<String> s=m.keySet();
Iterator<String> i=s.iterator();

Employee employee1=new Employee(Id,Name,Department,Salary);
m.get(Department.setId("Id");
ListForFinance.add(employee1);
m.put(Department, ListForFinance);

while(i.hasNext())
{
System.out.println(i.next());
}

break;
}



case 3:
{
System.out.println("=========================================================");
System.out.println("ID"+"\t"+"NAME"+"\t\t"+"DEPARTMENT"+"\t\t"+"SALARY");
System.out.println("=========================================================");
Set<String> s=m.keySet();
Iterator<String> i=s.iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) 
{
     String dept=i.next();
     List<Employee> employees=m.get(dept);
     for(int j=0;j<employees.size();j++)
     {
         System.out.print("\n"+employees.get(j)+"\n\n"); 
     }  
}
break;
}

}
}
}

catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("NOTE: \n"+"Please enter specified key format..!!!");
System.out.println("======================================");
System.out.println("Now you are Signing out");
System.out.println("Thank You,Login Again");
System.out.println("======================================"); 
}
}
}

default:
System.out.println("=============================================================";
System.out.print("Wrong key Pressed,please enter the correct key\n";
System.out.println("Try again...!!!";
System.out.println("=============================================================";
}
}
} 


Please find how to enter employee details,update,remove,displaying using hashmap wherin employee dept is taken as a key and id,name,salary is stored in the values using arraylist ......Currently Iam struck at CASE 2...PLease help me out
```

In CASE 1 i am trying to insert the employee details and in CASE 2 iam trying to modify the values .If i try to put any details with the same Dept it should create new entry...Even i should able to modify it,i am not getting how to do..PLease help me out

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, please format this wall of code, format your question, and explain what you need. Right now, this is not an acceptable question.

Comment: Sir,let me know how to add an employee details using hashmap and arrayList..Inputs should be taken from the user..I should be able to add,modify,remove,display the employee details according to the department..Hope u understood...

Comment: You haven't done anything to your question. As I said, you need to improve your question. You can do this by clicking the "edit" link. If you do not improve your question, it will probably be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear,
For setting employee in list

```
Arraylist<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employees>;
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setname("John");
emp.setEmpCode(1);
list.add(emp);
```

For getting employee from list just use this.

```
Employee emp = list.getItem(0);// change 0 to your position or make a loop to get all employees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*; import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Employee{

public String name; public String city; public String email; public String phone; public String age;`enter code here`

public Employee(String name,String city,String email,String age,String phone) { super(); this.name = name; this.city=city; this.email = email; this.age=age; this.phone = phone; }

public String getPhone() { return phone; }

public String getAge() { return age; }

public String getName() { return name; } public String getEmail() { return email; } public String getAddress() { return city; } public void setPhone(String phone) { this.phone = phone; } }

public class Display_Employee implements Comparator {

/* public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) { // in the case if when age is Integer return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge(); }*/ /public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) { //for short by Name return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName()); }/ public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) { //for short by Name return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge()); } public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { int choice,i,size,mob_serch_result,email_serch_result; String name,city,email,phone,age,mob_serch,email_serch,update_search,choice_update,update_search_email; String name1,city1,email1,phone1,age1;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// Map< String, List > mapPhone=new HashMap< String, List >(); // Map< String, List > mapEmail=new HashMap< String, List >(); Map< String, Integer > mapEmail=new HashMap< String, Integer >(); Map< String, Integer > mapPhone=new HashMap< String, Integer >(); List list = new ArrayList(); //User Input /*System.out.println("How much details you want to Enter"); size=sc.nextInt() ; for(i=0;i<size;i++) {

System.out.println("\t\t\t\tEnter the "+(i+1)+" Employee Details \t\t\t\t\n"); System.out.println("Enter the name "); name=sc.next(); System.out.println("Enter the City "); city=sc.next(); System.out.println("Enter the email "); email=sc.next(); System.out.println("Enter the age "); age=sc.next(); System.out.println("Enter the MobNum "); phone=sc.next(); Employee employee=new Employee(name,city,email,age,phone); list.add(employee); mapPhone.put(phone,i); mapEmail.put(email,i); }*/

//Testing input Employee employee1=new Employee("Raj","Mumbai","raj@yahoo.com","27","7499031600"); list.add(employee1); phone="7499031600"; email="raj@yahoo.com"; mapPhone.put(phone,0); mapEmail.put(email,0); Employee employee2=new Employee("Rekha","Chennai","rekha@hotmail.com","24","9598551664"); list.add(employee2); phone1="9598551664"; email1="rekha@hotmail.com"; mapPhone.put(phone1,1); mapEmail.put(email1,1); Employee employee3=new Employee("Ram","Siliguri","ram@outlook.com","55","8563878480"); list.add(employee3); String phone2="8563878480"; String email2="ram@outlook.com"; mapPhone.put(phone2,2); mapEmail.put(email2,2); Employee employee4=new Employee("Lakhan","Bhopal","Lakhan@outlook.com","30","8563050698"); list.add(employee4); String phone3="8563050698"; String email3="Lakhan@outlook.com"; mapPhone.put(phone3,3); mapEmail.put(email3,3); Employee employee5=new Employee("Bharat","Ayodhya","Bharat@outlook.com","35","9044669201"); list.add(employee5); String phone4="9044669201"; String email4="Bharat@outlook.com"; mapPhone.put(phone4,4); mapEmail.put(email4,4 );

for (Employee s : list) { System.out.println("\n\n"+s.getName()+" " +s.getAddress()+" " +s.getAge()+" " +s.getEmail()+" " +s.getPhone()); } /Seaching part/ while(true) { System.out.println("==========================================================================================================="); System.out.println("Press 1 for Sort by age\nPress 2 for find the Person by mobile number\nPress 3 for find the Person by email\nPress 4 for update the mobiel number"); choice= sc.nextInt(); sc.nextLine(); switch(choice) { case 1: Collections.sort(list, new Display_Employee ()); for (Employee s : list) { System.out.println(" Name : "+s.getName()+" City : " +s.getAddress()+" Age : " +s.getAge()+" Email : " +s.getEmail()+" Phone : " +s.getPhone()); } System.out.println("===========================================================================================================");

break;
/*case 1 is Running perfectly*/

case 2:
System.out.println("Enter the mobiel number of Employee ");
mob_serch=sc.next();
mob_serch_result=mapPhone.get(mob_serch);
System.out.println("Mobile mob_serch_result is "+mob_serch_result);
Employee Emp_phone_obj=(Employee)list.get(mob_serch_result);
System.out.println("Employee Name:  "+Emp_phone_obj.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_phone_obj.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_phone_obj.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_phone_obj.getAddress());
break;                                                                /*case 2 is Running perfectly*/
case 3:
System.out.println("Enter the emailId of Employee ");
email_serch=sc.nextLine();
email_serch_result=mapEmail.get(email_serch);
System.out.println("Email_serch_result is "+email_serch_result);
Employee Emp_email_obj=(Employee)list.get(email_serch_result);
System.out.println("Employee Name :  "+Emp_email_obj.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_email_obj.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_email_obj.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_email_obj.getAddress());
break;
case 4:
System.out.println("Enter the mobile number ");
update_search=  sc.next();
mob_serch_result=mapPhone.get(update_search);
Employee Emp_update_obj=(Employee)list.get(mob_serch_result);
update_search_email=Emp_update_obj.getEmail();
System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYour Search Result");
System.out.println(" Name:  "+Emp_update_obj.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_update_obj.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_update_obj.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_update_obj.getAddress());
System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPress Y or y for Confirm and Update\tPress N or n for Cancle");
choice_update=sc.next();
if(choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")||choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
{
  mapPhone.remove(update_search);
  mapEmail.remove(update_search_email);
  list.remove(Emp_update_obj);
  System.out.println("Enter the Firstname ");
  name1=sc.next();
  System.out.println("Enter the City ");
  city1=sc.next();
  System.out.println("Enter the email ");
  email1=sc.next();
  System.out.println("Enter the age ");
  age1=sc.next();
  System.out.println("Enter the MobNum ");
  phone1=sc.next();
  Employee employee=new Employee(name1,city1,email1,age1,phone1);
  list.add(employee);
  mapPhone.put(phone1,  mob_serch_result);
  mapEmail.put(email1,  mob_serch_result);
}
break;
default:
System.out.println("\n\t****Please give a valid Input****\t\n");
break;
} }

}//End of main() method }//end of DisplayArrayList class
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
class Employee implements Comparator<Employee> {
  private String name;
  private String city;
  private String email;
  private String phone;
  private int age;
  public Employee(){}
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
      this.name = Name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
      this.phone=null;
      this.phone = phone;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
      return phone;
    }

    public int getAge() {
      return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
      return email;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
      return city;
    }
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {        //  in the case if when age is Integer
      return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }

  }
  public class Display_Employee  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int choice,i,size,mob_serch_result,email_serch_result,age,age1;
      String name,city,email,phone,mob_serch,email_serch,update_search,choice_update,update_search_email;
      String name1,city1,email1,phone1,Update_choice,choice_update_for_phone,choice_update_for_email;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Map< String, Integer > mapEmail=new HashMap< String, Integer >();
      Map< String, Integer > mapPhone=new HashMap< String, Integer >();
      List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      /*
      System.out.println("How much details you want to Enter");
      size=sc.nextInt()  ;
      for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
      System.out.println("\t\t\t\tEnter the  "+(i+1)+"  Employee Details \t\t\t\t\n");
      System.out.println("Enter the name ");
      name=sc.next();
      System.out.println("Enter the City ");
      city=sc.next();
      System.out.println("Enter the email ");
      email=sc.next();
      System.out.println("Enter the age ");
      age=sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the MobNum ");
      phone=sc.next();
      Employee employee=new Employee();
      employee.setAge(age);
      employee.setName(name);
      employee.setCity(city);
      employee.setPhone(phone);
      employee.setEmail(email);
      list.add(employee);
      mapPhone.put(phone,i);
      mapEmail.put(email,i);
    }*/

    /*Test input Start*/
    name="Anoop";
    city="kanpur";
    email="anoop@gmail.com";
    age=23;
    phone="9415418279";
    Employee employee=new Employee();
    employee.setAge(age);
    employee.setName(name);
    employee.setCity(city);
    employee.setPhone(phone);
    employee.setEmail(email);
    list.add(employee);
    mapPhone.put(phone,0);
    mapEmail.put(email,0);

    /*Test input end*/

    for (Employee s : list)
    {
      System.out.println("\n\n"+s.getName()+" " +s.getAddress()+" " +s.getAge()+" " +s.getEmail()+" " +s.getPhone());
    }
    while(true)
    {
      System.out.println("===========================================================================================================");
      System.out.println("Press 1 for Sort by age\nPress 2 for find the Person by mobile number\nPress 3 for find the Person by email\nPress 4 for update the mobiel number\nPress 5 for print list and free the varible ");
      choice= sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      switch(choice)
      {
        case 1:
        Collections.sort(list,new Employee());
        for (Employee s : list)
        {
          System.out.println("  Name : "+s.getName()+"  City  : " +s.getAddress()+" Age : " +s.getAge()+" Email : " +s.getEmail()+"    Phone : " +s.getPhone());
        }
        System.out.println("===========================================================================================================");

        break;
        case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter the mobile number of Employee ");
        mob_serch=sc.next();
        mob_serch_result=mapPhone.get(mob_serch);
        System.out.println("Mobile mob_serch_result is "+mob_serch_result);
        Employee Emp_phone_obj=(Employee)list.get(mob_serch_result);
        System.out.println("Employee Name:  "+Emp_phone_obj.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_phone_obj.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_phone_obj.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_phone_obj.getAddress());
        break;
        case 3:
        System.out.println("Enter the emailId of Employee ");
        email_serch=sc.nextLine();
        email_serch_result=mapEmail.get(email_serch);
        System.out.println("Email_serch_result is "+email_serch_result);
        Employee Emp_email_obj=(Employee)list.get(email_serch_result);
        System.out.println("Employee Name :  "+Emp_email_obj.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_email_obj.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_email_obj.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_email_obj.getAddress());
        break;
        case 4:
        System.out.println("\033[H\033[2J"+"\n\n\t\t\tPress P to Edit PhoneNumber & Press E for Edit Email ");
        choice_update_for_phone=sc.next();
        choice_update_for_email=choice_update_for_phone;
        if(choice_update_for_phone.equalsIgnoreCase("P")||choice_update_for_phone.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
        {
          System.out.println("Enter the Old Mobile number ");
          update_search=sc.next();
          mob_serch_result=mapPhone.get(update_search);
          System.out.println("  mob_serch_result "+mob_serch_result);
          Employee Emp_update_obj_phone=(Employee)list.get(mob_serch_result);
          System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYour Search Result");
          System.out.println(" Name:  "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getAddress());
          System.out.println("\t\t\t\tPress Y or y for Confirm and Update\tPress N or n for Cancle");
          choice_update=sc.next();
          if(choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")||choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
          {
            System.out.println("Enter the New MobNum ");
            phone1=sc.next();
            Emp_update_obj_phone.setPhone(phone1);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tupdated entry is :\n");
            mapPhone.put(phone1,mob_serch_result);                                        //Map update
            System.out.println(" Name:  "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getAddress()+"  PhoneNumber : "+Emp_update_obj_phone.getPhone());
          }
        }
        else if(choice_update_for_email.equalsIgnoreCase("e")||choice_update_for_email.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
          System.out.println("Enter the old email ");
          update_search_email=  sc.next();
          email_serch_result=mapEmail.get(update_search_email);
          System.out.println(" email_serch_result = "+  email_serch_result);
          Employee Emp_update_obj_email=(Employee)list.get(email_serch_result);
          System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYour Search Result");
          System.out.println(" Name:  "+Emp_update_obj_email.getName()+"  Email : "+Emp_update_obj_email.getEmail()+"  Age : "+Emp_update_obj_email.getAge()+"  City : "+Emp_update_obj_email.getAddress());
          System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPress Y or y for Confirm and Update\tPress N or n for Cancle");
          choice_update=sc.next();
          if(choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")||choice_update.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
          {
            System.out.println("Enter the new email ");
            email1=sc.next();
            Emp_update_obj_email.setEmail(email1);
            mapEmail.put(email1,email_serch_result);
          }
        }
        break;
        case 5:
        Iterator<Employee> itr=list.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
          Employee employe = itr.next();
          System.out.print("  name:  "+employe.getName());
          System.out.print("  email:  "+employe.getEmail());
          System.out.print("  age:  "+employe.getAge());
          System.out.println("  phone:  "+employe.getPhone());
        }
        System.gc();
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("\n\t****Please give a valid Input****\t\n");
        break;
      }

    }
  }//End of main() method
}//end of DisplayArrayList class
```

Comment: Please describe something about your answer.

Comment: what type explanation you want bro 
run the program once you will easily understand  the functionality of the code